# insert value from intractive grid column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I need to insert record based on the value of my interactive grid..

i have checkbox if i select the checkbox then the record should get inserted.. while inserting i need to insert the record based on the cheque  number which is not apex_item, its one of the intractive report column..

SELECT a.APPROVER_MAIL_ID,b.CHEQUE_AMOUNT into v_user_mail,v_amt
FROM PDC_STATUS_HISTORY a, PDC_CHEQUE_RANGES b
WHERE APPROVAL_LEVEL=2 and a.RECEIPT_NUMBER=b.RECEIPT_NUMBER and CHEQUE_NUMBER=APEX_APPLICATION.G_f01(i);

Here APEX_APPLICATION.G_f01(i) is one of the column from select query of INTRACTIVE GRID

Comment: You tagged oracle11g, oracle10g - what version of apex are you on ? Pls only use relevant tags.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what exactly you're trying to achieve - preferrably with a reproducible example